# How to find a variable with a certain value

Tags: string, variables, ms-access, ide

I'm looking through a bunch of code to try and find the variable which has a path inside it, problem is there is lots of code and I don't know where to start looking for it as it could be in many files. I'm using Access VBA and I know there is a window where you can find the value inside of a variable, but I'm just curios to if there is a vise versa method where I can find a variable which contains a certain part of a string.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume Access 2k3, because you didn't specify and that's what I have in front of me.  The instructions will vary for 2K7 and 2K10, but it'll be the same principal.

Open up VBA Editor.  You can do this by opening any module in Design View, or open any form in Design View and click the View menu option, and then Code.

From the top menu, click Edit and then Find

Type in the string you're searching for.  Or part of it, if you don't mind a few fruitful hits.  I sometimes use part of the string just because Access may not like searching for the full string.

Access will take you to the piece of code you're looking for, and highlight it.  Depending on how your code was written, it may not be exactly where you think it should be but you can usually work backwards and find it.  Some people use global variables and set them up in a private sub, so if that's the case then you'll have to do a little hunting.